# why can CMake Build files not be generated correctly

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-gui

I am trying a simple test to see if CMake is working on my windows system correctly.
I keep getting a error.
Here is the command with the error.

```
cmake .
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19044.
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (add_executable):
No SOURCES given to target: main.cpp


CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

code for file named main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

std::cout << "hello world\n" << "this is a test" <<std::endl;

}
```

and my CMake file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(test)

add_executable(main.cpp)
```

I have used CMake in Linux before so not sure why this is failed.
I used Microsoft package manager to install it.
I am using the command line for this, i tried the GUI it also failed.
I have also deleted the CMake files and cache multiple times.
I have not been able to find anything online.

Comment: The first argument to `add_executable` is the **target name**, which should be followed by sources list. It seems you forgot to specify that argument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can't add a comment since my reputation is too low, so I will write an answer instead. In the last line of your CMakeLists.txt file

```
add_executable(main.cpp)
```

you are missing the name of the executable

```
add_executable(name_exe main.cpp)
```

CMake is telling you that in the error message. CMake tries to create a target main.cpp without source files, since CMake suggests the name of the executable at the first place in the command add_executable().

Comment: that worked, now how can i get it to spit out a makefile instead of .sln. the -g flag did not work for me

Comment: never mind i got it spit out a .exe file. Just had to run cmake --build .

Comment: To get a makefile you need to specify a Generator which creates makefiles. This should work with the -G flag, I don't know why this didn't work in your case. *.sln files are files for the msvc Compiler which you are using. You can see this in the output of CMake in your question. With cmake --build cmake will call the Compiler, msvc in your case, directly.